# Calculating a parking fine using double

Tags: java, integer, double, calculation

I am working on a study exercise and wondering if I can get some guidance and the output is not as expected.

We need to calculate a fine for delayed payment. The parameters are the price of the parking fine and the number of days late. The fine should be calculated as 10% of the price of the fine, per day late. The method should return the fine in a double value.

Whilst the code has been accepted, it is not outputting the correct answer in the examples I have run, whilst calling the method. I think I'm not declaring the double correctly?

Thank you for any assistance you can provide.

```java
public class Fines
{
    // instance variables
    private ArrayList<Tickets> fines;
    private String test; 

    /**
     * Create a database
     */
    public Database(String aDatabase)
    {
       books = new ArrayList<>();
       name = aDatabase;
    }
    /**
     * Calculate fine for a late paid ticket
     */
    public double CalculateFine(int finePrice, int daysLate)
    {
        int amountToCharge;
        int percentAmount;
        percentAmount = 10*finePrice/100;
        amountToCharge = percentAmount*daysLate;
        return amountToCharge;
    }
}
```

Comment: Indeed, if you intended those variables to be `double`s, they are currently both defined as `int`s, which will cause rounding errors. You need to define the `percentAmount` and `amountToCharge` as `double` instead of an `int`.

Comment: Doh - I now feel stupid! Thanks

Comment: Recognizing that you're too deep in code to recognize a problem is a big step towards correcting the problem. This is why rubber-ducking works so well - https://www.rubberduk.com.

Comment: @spork please consider converting your comment into an answer so that it can be accepted by OP as the answer. This would ”closed” the question and helping others easily understand which could be a possible solution for similar questions ;) Thanks!

Comment: @JoãoDias sorry, didn't see your message until almost 2 mos later. I'll convert my comment right now.

Answer (score 2):

If you intended those variables to be `doubles`, they are currently both defined as `int`s which will cause rounding errors. You need to define the `percentAmount` and `amountToCharge` as `double` instead of an `int`.

This is a good example of knowing the answer to the problem but being too deep in the code to recognize it. It's often helpful to stop everything and explain the problem to yourself from Step 1 as though you're talking to an idiot.

Comment: "stop everything and explain the problem to yourself" Wise words. [Rubberduck debugging](https://rubberduckdebugging.com/) should be used more often.

Comment: @EricAya I created https://www.rubberduk.com so I have access to a duck anywhere I might be.